# Get open Apps on Mac with Python

Tags: python, macos, process, operating-system

I'm trying to get a list of open apps on my mac using python and then use mysql to save them on the server... I was hoping to use subprocess, but the result is not what I'm looking for

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far

Comment: I uploaded the pic here: https://applss.co.za/internal/one.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[psutils](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#processes) might help you:

```
import psutils
list(psutil.process_iter())
```

```
[psutil.Process(pid=0, name='kernel_task', started='2019-01-26 16:05:40'),
 psutil.Process(pid=1, name='launchd', started='2019-01-26 16:05:40'),
 psutil.Process(pid=40, name='syslogd', started='2019-01-26 16:05:45'),
 ...]
```

Also you can parse `ps aux` yourself:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['ps','aux'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.readlines()
```

```
[b'USER               PID  %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND\n',
 b'username           7834   7,9  9,5  7643484 797292   ??  S     4:03     4:32.77 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox\n',
 b'username           7839   6,9  3,4  5363256 285900   ??  R     4:03     0:11.68 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2\n',
 ...]
```

Comment: Thanks :) just what I needed